# Dubious syntax to access array content

Tags: c, arrays, syntax

In some legacy code I have to maintain, & operators are put in front of arrays names whenever the arrays are to be passed as (void *) arguments

Here is a simple example :

```
char val = 42;
char tab[10];
memcpy(&tab, &val, 1);
```

It compiles with gcc or clang without errors or warnings. It also gives the expected result.

Is this syntax legal ?

Why does this works ?

Notes : I usually use one of the following syntax :

```
memcpy(tab, &val, 1);
memcpy(&tab[0], &val, 1);
```

**Epilog :**

As an additional test, I used a function taking a (char*) argument instead of (void*)

I get the following warning if I try to compile with clang :

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[10]' to parameter of type 'char *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

*Edit 1 :
In the original example tab was given with a size of 1 element*

I just changed the size to 10 for the sake of generality.

Edit 2 :
As mentionned in the answers, memcpy takes (void*) and not (char*)

Comment: May as well throw in `memcpy(a+0, &val, 1)` just to cover third base too. (and I usually use *your* first example in *your* usual usage pattern).

Comment: Did you mean `memcpy(&tab, &val, 1)`?

Comment: The name of the array is already equivalent to a pointer to its first element.  Using the & operator is not necessary, it isn't wrong either.

Comment: @HansPassant: `tab` and `&tab` are of different types. Both are valid only because `memcpy()` takes arguments of type `void*`.

Comment: @mbratch: Only because `memcpy` takes arguments of type `void*`; see my previous comment and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19469786/827263).

Comment: strlen()'s argument is not void*.

Comment: Nothing about the syntax is dubious. Your question is about the semantics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`memcpy`'s parameters are of type `void*`, not `char*`. Any argument of pointer type (excluding function pointers) is implicitly converted to `void*`. This is a special-case rule that applies only to `void*`.

Given the declaration

```
char tab[1];
```

either `tab` or `&tab` is valid as an argument to `memcpy`. They evaluate to pointers of different types (`char*` and `char (*)[1]`), but both pointing to the same memory location; converting either to `void*` yields the same value.

For a function that actually requires a `char*` argument, only `tab` is valid; `&tab` is of the wrong type. (For a variadic function like `printf` or `scanf`, the compiler may not be able to detect the type mismatch.)

Comment: A big **+1** (and I wish I could up-vote it twice) for pointing out the differences between the resulting pointer types and their valid usage scenarios.

Comment: I think it perfectly answers my question. Thanks !

Comment: @haccks: Or both. (Neither is required.)